# Why am I getting a 500 internal server error with my Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, cgi, cpanel

I am using perl 5.10.1 and the path to perl is `/usr/bin/perl`

I've chmoded the file to 755 and I am getting an internal server error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "huh";
```

The code is so simple, I have no idea what's causing this. I am also running a forum software that was coded in Perl and it works fine and uses the same path.

edit: Thanks for everyone's help, I created another folder and added a cgi-bin in there and tried the script, it works. I still have no idea why it wouldn't work in the first one, a bud edited my .htaccess file in the first folder that could be the problem.

Comment: Does the script run from the prompt? Perhaps bad line endings?

Comment: i have no idea how to run from the prompt. if you mean by SSH i don't have SSH access

Comment: the script (as you shows above) hasn't any problem. It will runs fine as- apache's cgi-bin script. So the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: Do you have access to the error log?

Comment: Is Perl installed? Is it located at `/usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: Perhaps you need enter the script name as script-alias or something like in httpd-server config? (do you have apache? or what?)

Comment: yes perl is installed, in the cpanel home it says:

Path to Perl:  /usr/bin/perl
Perl version:  5.10.1

yes i have access to error logs, but it doesn't seem to tell me whats going on:

[Thu Mar 27 22:45:31 2014] [error] [client ip_address] File does not exist: /home/cpaneluser54783/public_html/forum/500.shtml

Comment: Look in the logs. It will tell you what happened.

Comment: yes i am using apache version 2.2.26

Comment: Please post as much information as possible in your own answer to the question, and accept it. It will help other people with the same problem and will mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the correct spelling is [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17).

There may be a problem with buffering (the output amount is small, there is no newline at the end etc ...) It just makes me suspicious. This is the minimal script I would try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);

local $| = 1;

print header('text/plain'), "huh\n";
```

Did you FTP the file from a Windows PC to a Unix system? If you transferred the file in binary mode, the shebang line will not be correct.

For example:

```
$ unix2dos t.pl
unix2dos: converting file t.pl to DOS format ...
$ xxd t.pl
0000000: 2321 2f75 7372 2f62 696e 2f70 6572 6c0d  #!/usr/bin/perl.
0000010: 0a0d 0a70 7269 6e74 2022 4041 5247 565c  ...print "@ARGV\
0000020: 6e22 3b0d 0a                             n";..
$ ./t.pl hello world
zsh: ./t.pl: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/perl^M: no such file or directory
```

Comment: While youre 100% right with the "Content-Type" - i just tried the script under my Apache and it works ;)

Comment: i tried using that and it still doesn't work. i posted a thread on my cpanel provider forums they will be able to dig around and hopefully find the problem. thanks